# React frontend, Node JS backend to hosting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting

How to host an application React js with node js backend.  Couldn't find anything on the internet.  Do I need to run the
`build`
command on the backend?  Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try just doing `nodejs hosting` in a google search.?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use **Heroku**, you get to host your full stack application for free, directly from your GitHub repository, it automatically redeploys whenever you push something on your repo.

The only – slight – downside is having to wait ~5 seconds for the server to start up if your app hasn't been visited for a while and becomes idle (if you use a free option that is).

There are plenty of tutorials on how to do so.

As for serving the static version to your app in production — this could be of use:

***server.js***

```
/* If in production mode - serve compressed/static react content to server. i.e. what would be otherwise localhost:5000 would display frontend content.
/!\ Do not forget to generate Procfile and script for Heroku to insure proper generation of "build" directory /!\ */

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend/build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Heroku will take care of it automatically if you tell your server to serve the static version with the code above.

There is also [Glitch.com](https://glitch.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it:
I build my react project and host it on the server.
As for node js, I run it on it’s own, and use Pm2 to run it on the server ( https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/ ) but there’s plenty of other ways you can find on google.

I hope I answered your question